# TypeScript value declarations of interfaces with all optional members are treated as <any>

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript1.8

The following code is valid TypeScript

```
interface AllMembersOptional {
    first?: string;
    second?: number;
}

let a: AllMembersOptional = 7;
let b: AllMembersOptional = () => 7;
```

and because Angular's IComponentOptions interface is defined as

```
interface IComponentOptions {
    controller?: string | Function | (string | Function)[] | IComponentController;
    controllerAs?: string;
    template?: string | Function | (string | Function)[];
    templateUrl?: string | Function | (string | Function)[];
    bindings?: {[binding: string]: string};
    transclude?: boolean | string | {[slot: string]: string};
    require?: {[controller: string]: string};
}
```

then the following are valid TypeScript as well:

```
angular.module('test').component('custom', function () {
    return {
        controller: 'testCtrl',
        template: '<div></div>,
        //...
    };
});

angular.module('test').component('custom', 7);

angular.module('test').component('custom', "hello");

angular.module('test').component('custom', new Date());
```

None of this code actually works at run-time but TypeScript compiles without errors and is Working as Intended

Should the TypeScript compiler generate 'bad/incompatible type' errors for the above examples?
Or should empty interfaces be disallowed (e.g. via a compiler switch)?
Or do nothing and just accept this is how it's going to work?

Answer (score 1):

This has already been logged as [issue 7485](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7485). At time of writing, it hasn't been resolved.